# Get price from two tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get the product price, but I have it in two tables (because I have different price control). Here's my schema:

```
Product table:
- SKU 
- msrp 
- price
- disponible

Price table:
- SKU
- price
- disponible_from
- disponible_to
- period_from
- period_to
- priority
```

What I want it to do:

1) First check in price table (`order by priority DESC`). E.g. check if `period_from` is bigger and `period_from` is smaller than current date. Also check if disponible of the product with that SKU is bigger and smaller than `disponible_from` and `disponible_to`

E.g. if I have a product with `disponible = 100`, and I have a price where `disponible_from is 200`, it should NOT get the price from price table, but get it from product table. If `disponible_from` was 50, and product disponible 100, it SHOULD get price from price table.

2) If no matches in price table, it should get the price from product table. If price in product table is not filled, it should return the msrp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ifnull( price.price, ifnull( product.price, product.msrp ))
from  price
join product on price.sku = product.sku 
     and (product.disponible > ifnull( price.disponible_from, "1970-01-01" )
         and product.disponible < ifnull( price.disponible_to, curdate()))
where ( price.periodfrom < curdate() and price.periodto > curdate());
```

Comment: I'm getting an error near 'on' in the code. Also, this one expects periodfrom and periodto to be filled - but they can be empty. Sometimes they are filled, and sometimes empty. Can you fix it?

Comment: edited. If periodfrom/to are empty - what do they default to?

Comment: Then they're just empty. The problem I have is that, if I want the price to be active from e.g. 2012-02-01, then I only fill out periodfrom, and then it should work from that date and onwards. Also, if it's only periodto that's filled, then it should only get it until that date. Same thing with disponible. E.g. if only disponible_from is filled or only disponible_to is filled.

You get the idea?

Comment: Hmm sorry guys, but I can't get it working. It looks like it expects disponible_from and disponible_to to be filled, and that's not always the case. As with period_from and to, disponible_from and to can be empty. See this pastebin: http://pastebin.com/BAfjaKLD